# Can programmatically upload objects to S3 bucket but GET request is forbidden

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing a django app which needs file uploads. I've created an S3 bucket and an IAM user with `S3FullAccess` permissions. I took the access key ID and the secret access key and put them in my code (using env variables). I'm using `django_storages` to send uploaded files to S3, and my config in my settings file is

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<my bucket name>'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

The CORS policy for the bucket for now is

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Using this configuration, I'm able to upload files to the S3 bucket from my application, but when that file is requested by the application (by just a direct link to the object in the bucket), I get a `403 Forbidden` error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Requested by your application how?  Using the S3 API, a direct unauthenticated HTTP(S) request to the bucket's public endpoint?  Something else?

Comment: Please Edit your Question to show us your code and the permissions associated with the credentials being used.

Comment: By requested I mean a direct link to the object's public uri. I'm mostly uploading images so I'm adding the link to the object in the src attribute of an image

Comment: Are you uploading with public ACLs?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what that means, but I haven't set any ACLs, and under the permissions tab for the bucket, I can see `ACLs are disabled. All objects in this bucket are owned by this account. Access to this bucket and its objects is specified using only policies.`